# Approach for adding randomly placed rectilinear rectangles to a plane of fixed size

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I have a rectangle size n x n and I need to place k randomly placed rectangles on the plane.  Also, the rectangles cannot intersect (not ever edge intersections of 0 area). I'm having trouble thinking of approaches to this problem.

One idea I had was to divide the plane into square regions and fill each region with a rectangle of random width and height and center (but the guarentee that it won't touch the edge of the small container square it is in). The problem with this approach is that the rectangles are to evenly distributed.

Another was to pick k points and for each point find the closest point to it. Then give the point width and length equal to an amount that guarantees that it can't intersect the other points (using radius and pythagorean theorem). The problem with this approach was that the rectangles ended up being way too small and all of rather similar size when k was high relative to the area of the plane.

Any ideas for an approach to this problem?

EDIT: Another constraint is that the coordinates for the rectangle and dimensions should be integers, but this one can be relaxed due to the existence of CEIL and FLOOR :P

Comment: Are the rectangles axis aligned or can they have arbitrary orientation? Maybe you can get some inspiration from http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/

Comment: Their sides are parallel to the x and y axis! Thats what rectilinear means btw :P

Comment: ooooh that's cool, definitely spending my next 15 mins on that article

Comment: `n x n` makes a square not rectangle, you sure? how?

Comment: The plane we are placing the rectangles in is of size n x n! Also squares are rectangles, hahahahaha~

Comment: Mr E, I like that algorithm. It works very well for high k, but for most of my situations, I'll be having a lowish k. When this algorithm has low k compared to the grid size you choose, it starts to have the same problem that my first approach had

Comment: But I might use this for my larger n valued planes

Answer (score 0):

So i made an algorithm of my own. Here's how it works:

1. Create open_list, an array of disjoint rectangles that designate "free" space on the map.
2. Add a rectangle covering the map to the list
3. Find a random rectangle R in the open_list (I did this weighing the rectangles by area)
4. Choose a random height and width from 1 to some fraction of the width/height inclusive. The fraction is to give you some "buffer space" but it's not necessary.
5. Choose a random x and y from a random number from 0 to some fraction of width and height inclusive.
6. Create the rectangle at x+buffer,y+buffer.
7. Remove R from the open_list
8. Create 4 rectangles to take up the open space that is remaining. I had it so that the top and bottom were bigger or left right were bigger based on a random variable, that way the obstacles weren't left or right heavy in position.
9. Add them to the open_list.
10. Do steps 3-9 to make another obstacle!